# É possível fazer um update nas 100 primeiras linhas no sql(server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE tbl_venda
SET produto=1
WHERE produto=3
```

O problema é que são mais de 10.000 linhas de vendas e o pc trava.
Gostaria se era possível fazer de 100 em 100, 500 em 500, pra não ficar pesado.

Comment: Qual a estrutura da tabela tbl_venda? Há coluna que indique a data e hora da venda, por exemplo?

Comment: o que necessita é atualizar os produtos de código 3 para código 1 ou o código SQL que transcreveu é somente um modelo?

Answer (score 4):

Isso é possível, só colocar um `TOP(100)` após o update, ex:

```
UPDATE top(100) tbl_venda
SET produto=1
WHERE produto=3
```

Answer (score 3):

Se o que necessita é tão-somente alterar o código de produto 3 para 1 nas linhas da tabela tbl_venda, como está no código que transcreveu para este tópico, então a solução é simples.

```
-- código #1
declare @Continua int, @tamBloco int;
set @tamBloco= 500;
set @Continua= 1;

while (@Continua > 0)
  begin
  --
  UPDATE top (@tamBloco) tbl_venda
    set produto= 1
    where produto = 3;
  -- 
  set @Continua= @@rowcount;
  -- pausa (10 segundos entre execuções: "pra não ficar pesado")
  waitfor delay '0:00:10';
  end;
```

No código acima, a variável @tamBloco informa de quantas em quantas linhas ocorrerá a atualização; ajuste para o valor desejado.

A instrução UPDATE é executada várias vezes, até que não haja mais linhas para atualizar.

Answer (score 2):

Com o TOP:

```
UPDATE top (100) tbl_venda
SET produto=1
WHERE produto=3
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198364/how-can-i-update-top-100-records-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a palavra reservada ***top***, conforme segue:

```
UPDATE top (100) tbl_venda
SET produto=1
WHERE produto=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Sem a clausula `ORDER BY` a definição de `TOP` não faz muito sentido. Você precisa de uma ordem para saber o que é 'para cima' e 'para baixo'

Embora o servidor aceite não é garantido quais registros serão afetados.

Algo assim é mais consistente.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM TBL_VENDA WHERE PRODUTO=3 AND ID >= PROXIMO_ID
ORDER BY ID
) 
UPDATE CTE SET PRODUTO=1
```

A variavel proximo_id começa com 0 no primeiro UPDATE e deve assumir outros valores a medida que o updates vão sendo feitos, porque senão você não consegue dar updates nos próximos registros.

Comment: No caso específico deste tópico, me parece que não é necessário o ORDER BY pois o que está sendo alterado é o código do produto (de 3 para 1) vendido. A cada execução do UPDATE virão sempre as linhas que ainda não foram atualizadas.